# MODx Gallery plugin doesn't show full images

Tags: gallery, modx-revolution

I have Gallery plugin installed.

I've uploaded my images and used snippet like this: `[[Gallery? &album=`1`]]`.

Now I have thumbnails shown fine, but after clicking on image I'm sent to `/index.php?id=4&galItem=2&galAlbum=1&galTag=` address and nothing happens - this page is the same as the previous one.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: sounds like it could be a problem with your thumbTpl, or possibly even furls... is there an example we can see working? [try calling it uncached as well.]

Comment: what does your thumbTpl Chunk look like?

Comment: @SeanKimball I have no such a chunk. There's default one, isn't it?

Comment: PS There was a link to my project, so I delited related comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the link to your page with id=4. In this page you have to get galItem, galAlbum and galTag and show corresponding image. I'm not sure you have handling this in your template.

Just try this:

```
[[Gallery? &album=1 &linkToImage=`1`]]
```

You will get the direct link to your image if you keep your thumbTpl chunk as in sample:

```
  <a href="[[+linkToImage:if=`[[+linkToImage]]`:is=`1`:then=`[[+image_absolute]]`:else=`[[~[[*id]]?
            &[[+imageGetParam]]=`[[+id]]`
            &[[+albumRequestVar]]=`[[+album]]`
            &[[+tagRequestVar]]=`[[+tag]]` ]]`]]">
```

Now you just get `else` part.

Comment: Yes. You were right. I misunderstood how Gallery works. Thank you. How I'm using [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/guide)